# Preventing user in G-sheet to paste data in Data validation existed cells and allow only from dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have 8 branches in different parts of the city and set up one process to collect the branch data through google sheet. We told them to select only from dropdown provided in the sheet, but few are copying and pasting it in those cells. Since, they have edit permissions, it is allowing them to do so. Can anyone help me on this how to restrict the user to paste data in those cells?

Thanks!

I tried to protect it then it is completely blocked to enter data. I want to allow the user to enter the data from the given dropdown values and strictly not allowed to paste in those cells from any source.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question doesn't look to be about programming. The question doesn't include formulas and scripts. It mentions *data validation* and *protection*, but the question looks to be leaning toward **using** Google Sheets rather than programming. Why is the [tag:google-apps-script] tag included on it?

Answer (score 0):

**Attempting to overcome the notorious posting in an onEdit problem**

Evidently this has been a problem for a long time.  I use onEdit sparingly and I always leave my toasts enabled so that I know that it's complete before I start another one.  Yeah, I know your clients are probably in a hurry and they don't want to wait.  But I and you know if they don't then they risk the quality of the data their collecting.  Anyway, I suspect a lot of people have tried different things and this is my simplistic approach which appears to work in my limited application, which only involved 10 cells in a column.

GS:

```
function setDV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A1:A10");
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireValueInList(["one", "two", "three"]);
  rg.setDataValidation(r);
}
function clrDV() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A1:A10");
  rg.clearDataValidations();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("onEdit Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd && e.range.columnStart == e.range.columnEnd && e.value) {
    e.source.toast("onEdit Gate1")
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let col1Obj = ps.getProperty("COL1DV");
    if (!col1Obj) {
      col1Obj = {};
      col1Obj[e.range.getA1Notation()] = e.value;
      ps.setProperty("COL1DV", JSON.stringify(col1Obj))
    } else {
      col1Obj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty("COL1DV"));
      col1Obj[e.range.getA1Notation()] = e.value;
      ps.setProperty("COL1DV", JSON.stringify(col1Obj));
    }
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart != e.range.rowEnd) {
    e.source.toast("onEdit Gate2");
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let col1Obj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty("COL1DV"));
    breakUpRangeList(e.source,sh,sh.getRangeList([e.range.getA1Notation()])).getRanges().forEach(rg => {
      let a1 = rg.getA1Notation();
      if(col1Obj.hasOwnProperty(a1)) {
        sh.getRange(a1).setValue(col1Obj[a1])
      }
    })
    clrDV();
    setDV();
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)